# How to set font size and position in specific text

Tags: angular, npm, jspdf, angular-library, jspdf-autotable

I want to set font size and position in a specific text.how can i do that?

```
doc.text( 40, 30, "jspdf" );
```

[image]

Comment: did you check the documentation http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#setFontSize

Comment: @Gopal I use jsPDF-autotable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    doc.setFontSize(20);
    doc.text(
      "SHARJAS",
      40,
      30
    );

    doc.setFontSize(18);
    doc.text(
      `SHARJAS`,
      40,
      50
    );
 doc.setFontSize(16);
    doc.text(
      `SHARJAS`,
      40,
      70
    );
 doc.setFontSize(14);
    doc.text(
      `SHARJAS`,
      40,
      70
    );
```